# Is there a command to convert the content of an ASCII file to normal text straight from the linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, ascii

I have a file with the file type "ASCII file" and I was wondering if there was a command to convert the contents of this file into human readable text without using an online text conversion tool?

Comment: ASCII file is already readable, no conversion is needed. How do you check "file type"? Did you try researching what "ASCII" is and what is "ASCII file"? What online conversion tool were you trying to use with what options?

Comment: Ahh I see, I used "file [file name]" to check the file type.

Comment: Then use `cat` to print it. See also `cat --help`  - you might be interested in `cat -V` or `cat -T` or similar options.